# React-Navigation V6 Drawer.Item drawerItemStyle: { display: "none" } still renders DrawerItem in react-test-renderer

Tags: react-native, react-test-renderer, react-native-testing-library, jest-expo, testing-libraryreact-native

I am trying to write a test where Drawer item goes from invisible to visible. The way I am implementing the visibility switch is by toggling the `drawerItemStyle` prop on the Drawer item from `display: "none"` to `display: "flex"`. This works in an android emulator. However, when I render the Drawer navigator with react native testing library the DrawerItem is present even when the drawerItemStyle prop is set to `display: "none"`.

With this:

```js
<DrawerStack.Screen
  name="Name"
  component={Component}
  options={{
    title: "Title",
    drawerItemStyle: {
      display: "none",
    },
  }}
/>
```

This test passes:

```js
const { getByText } = render(<DrawerNavigator />);
getByText("Title")
```

1. Is it expected that setting display "none" will still render it in react-test-renderer?
2. Is there a better way to toggle the visibility?
3. Is there a better way to test the visibility?

### Update: Solution Found

I had to do this:

```
const { container } = render(<Component />);
const drawerItemsProps = container .findAllByType(DrawerItem).map((e: any) => e.props);
const targetProps = drawerItemsProps[drawerItemsProps.findIndex((e: any) => e.label === "Title")];
const { style: { display },  } = targetProps;
expect(display).toEqual('none');
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, please post it as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically how i got it working in the end:

```
const { container } = render(<Component />);
const drawerItemsProps = container.findAllByType(DrawerItem).map((e: any) => e.props);
const targetProps = drawerItemsProps[drawerItemsProps.findIndex((e: any) => e.label === "Title")];
const { style: { display }, } = targetProps;
expect(display).toEqual('none');
```

Answer (score 1):

As the item is present in the render, it's expected for RNTL to find it. You could check the visibility with the [toHaveStyle](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-native#tohavestyle) matcher from the [additional jest matchers](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library#additional-jest-matchers)

```
const { getByText } = render(<DrawerNavigator />);
expect(getByText("Title")).toHaveStyle({display: 'none'});
```

Comment: I imagine if this worked then the getByText would fail. I had to do this: 

```
const { container } = render(<Component />);
 const drawerItemsProps = container
    .findAllByType(DrawerItem)
    .map((e: any) => e.props);
  const targetProps =
    drawerItemsProps[
      drawerItemsProps.findIndex((e: any) => e.label === "Title")
    ];
```